# Prevent a ..Net Console app from opening a browser

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I inherited a 'Core' Console app that opens a browser.  I only need it to work as a console app but it has a Program.cs file with this content...

```
  public static void Main(string[] args)
     {
       var host = new WebHostBuilder()
           .UseKestrel()
           .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
           .UseIISIntegration()
           .UseStartup<THIS_CLASS_NAME>()
           .Build();

        host.Run();
   }

public void Configure() { }
```

How do I prevent it from opening a browser? There are no models or controllers in this project.  Just this Program.cs file.  It set as a Console app.

Comment: Your project has a `launchsettings.json` file.  Look at that file.

Comment: That works!  How do I get rid of that code and still have it run whatever I call from Main?

Comment: How do you get rid of *what* code?  The code in the question?

Comment: Yes!  It doesn't seem to be needed?  The code in the Main I mean

Comment: The code in the question starts a web application, which you inherited.  Is that web application needed?

Comment: It's a Console app actually.  So I didn't think it was needed.  Now that it does not open a browser I didn't think the WebHostBuilder object was needed.

Comment: .... it's a console app that hosts a web application... if you think the startup code for an application that you inherited isn't needed, I would rethink that.

Comment: I inherited the stem but I chopped it down to its bare essentials and the web part of it is no longer needed.

Comment: If you don't want to host an instance of a server, as a console app, remove the code.  An extra tip is..  look in Startup.cs.  Its called from `host.Run()` and you likely have logic there you are wanting to use. Best I can give with info I have.

Comment: Well if the web part is no longer needed, then you can remove it, I guess.

Comment: I removed the Startup.cs file.  And moved an empty Configure() method into the Main.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Right click on the project in VS and go to Properties.
- Then in Debug uncheck Launch browser.

Comment: This seems to be it as well.   Is there a way to dispense with that code I posted?  If I delete it, then whatever other method I call from the Main does not get called.

Comment: The code you posted very generally hosts an instance of a server.  `WebHostBuilder` is from `AspNetCore`.  Once you reach `host.Run()`, you stay inside there most the lifetime of the instance.  Comment out your `var host...` and `host.Run()` and add `Console.WriteLine("Hello")`.

Comment: I'm trying to call an API and if I remove that code,  the call to the API fails.  I think it needs to persist in runtime via that code.

Comment: @john Please take note: the original question was "how do I stop this from launching a browser?"  The question has changed.  If you have another question to ask, accept your current answer if it helped you and ask a new question.  Don't move the goal post.